# Vue indeterminate checkbox binding

Tags: checkbox, binding, vue.js

I am using vue for data binding.
I want to create a widget for access level control so I need allow, deny, and indeterminate states.

This markup is good but there is no indeterminate state:

```
<div class="row" v-for='a in context.This.Actions'>
    <div class="col-96">
        <input class="custom-control-input access-checkbox" v-bind:id="'chk_'+a.Name" v-bind:value="a.Id" v-model="context.This.RoleActions" indeterminate="true" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="pointer" v-bind:for="'chk_'+a.Name">{{ a.Name }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The variables are :

```
context.This.Actions = [
    { "Id": "id_1",
      "Name": "AAA"
    },
    { "Id": "id_2",
      "Name": "BBB"
    },
    { "Id": "id_3",
      "Name": "CCC"
    }
]

context.This.RoleActions = [ "id_1", "id_2" ]
```

I want this change:

```
context.This.RoleActions = [ {"id_1":true}, {"id_2":false} ]
```

and I expect the below result:

- The first checkbox: checked
- The second checkbox: unchecked
- The other one: indeterminate

Answer (score 21):

Indeterminate is a DOM property on a checkbox, which means putting it in the markup won't have an effect, it needs to be applied programmatically.

Even after doing that, keep in mind the state of a checkbox is still either checked or not checked. This is important to keep in mind when processing the form. The difference is visual only. [(source)](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/)

With those caveats in mind, in Vue 2 you can add an indeterminate property to a checkbox like so:

`<input type="checkbox" indeterminate.prop="true">`

or bind to a dynamic value in your component:

`<input type="checkbox" :indeterminate.prop="dataProperty">`

I would recommend refactoring with this in mind.

Comment: Here is the reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4094#issuecomment-261659740

Answer (score 1):

**I had a similar issue using props with checkbox to support 2 and 3 states .
to handle this I used computed property with getter and setter using Vuetify checkbox**

Here is my example

```
<template>
  <v-container class="checkbox-container">
    <v-checkbox
      type="checkbox"
      :indeterminate="indeterminate"
      :color="indeterminate ? '#767575' : 'success'"
      v-model="internalState"
      @click.stop="onCheckbox"
      @keyup.space.prevent="onCheckbox"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
/**
 * Responsability: boolean field editor checkbox
 * When @threeState is true : following states (check, uncheck, indeterminate) otherwise (check, uncheck)
 * @checkboxState is an external state where it contains always the current state of checkbox
 **/
export default {
  model: {
    // v-model prop
    prop: 'checkboxState',
  },
  props: {
    threeState: Boolean,
    /**
     * Init state is the starting state Which the chekbox starts from.
     * by defining initstate it will ignore the default input @boolProperty
     **/
    initState: {
      type: String,
      default: 'false',
    },
    // Reperesent the value of checked state in model
    config: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        checked: 'true',
        unchecked: 'false',
        indeterminate: null,
      }),
    },
    checkboxState: {
      type: String,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      internalState: this.checkboxState,
      indeterminate: false,
    }
  },

  computed: {
    state: {
      get() {
        return this.checkboxState
      },
      set(newState) {
        this.changeCheckboxState(newState)
      },
    },
  },

  // Change the state of checkbox after DOM is mounted
  mounted() {
    this.changeCheckboxState(this.initState)
  },

  methods: {
    changeCheckboxState(state) {
      this.$vnode.data.model.callback(state)
      this.internalState = state === this.config.checked
      this.indeterminate = state === this.config.indeterminate
    },

    onCheckbox() {
      if (this.threeState) {
        switch (this.state) {
          case this.config.unchecked:
            this.state = this.config.checked
            break
          case this.config.checked:
            this.state = this.config.indeterminate
            break
          case this.config.indeterminate:
            this.state = this.config.unchecked
            break
        }
      } else {
        this.state = (!(this.state === this.config.checked)).toString()
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.checkbox-container {
  width: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```js
<template>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :indeterminate="isIndeterminate"
    :checked="isChecked"
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', isChecked)"
    @click="toggleCheckState"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: { type: Boolean, default: undefined }
})
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const isChecked = ref<boolean | undefined>(false)
const isIndeterminate = ref(false)

onMounted(() => {
  if (props.modelValue == undefined) isIndeterminate.value = true
  else isChecked.value = props.modelValue
})

function toggleCheckState() {
  if (isIndeterminate.value) {
    isChecked.value = true
    isIndeterminate.value = false
  } else if (isChecked.value == false) {
    isChecked.value = undefined
    isIndeterminate.value = true
  } else {
    isChecked.value = false
    isIndeterminate.value = false
  }
}
</script>
```

Usage

```
<SmartCheckbox v-model="anyRef" /> 

{{ anyRef}}
```